# php imap_fetchbody; ignore history, just fetch the current message

Tags: php, imap

I am trying to fetch only the current message and ignore the message trail. Here is the message that I fetched using imap_fetchbody():

```
OK, see you there.
```

On Mon, Aug 27, 2012 at 12:13 PM, Symantec Briefing Tool  wrote:

```
You are invited to the following meeting. The following is a
time we have tentatively scheduled you.
```

....

Here, I need to get only the part "OK, see you there." and ignore the rest of the message history. How can I do that? any ideas or pointers are highly appreciated. I have tried using imap_fetchtext and imap_fetchbody but no luck???

Comment: Well, that *is* the body of the message. The quoted parts are part of the message. What you're asking for is *how to filter quoted parts out of a message*, which is not a job for IMAP.

Comment: OK, after you comment I understand that its not the job of imap, but is there a set of functions available which can do the job for me? what I have done for the time being is I have tweaked the body text by using string functions which look ugly and dont look efficient.